# Android SDK Random and SecureRandom returning not so random values

Tags: java, android, random

**TLDR:** I have a *singleton* with:

```
Random random = new SecureRandom(); // tried with new Random() as well
```

I use the same instance to call *random.nextInt(3)* and I get results like: 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2. Lots of '2', but not so many '0' or '1'. What happens?

**Long version**: I have a game where enemies use one of 3 skills randomly (by doing *random.nextInt(3)*) and they always end up using the same skill over and over. Both in emulator and on phone. Very very rarely they use a different skill.

Of course, doing 1000 *random.nextInt(3)* calls in a test will return seemingly random values, but not in my game. And I only instantiated Random/SecureRandom once and use it as a singleton.

On very rare occasions, it does the opposite: 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0. I don't understand what's happening or how to fix it.

Comment: By what definition `2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2` would be a not-so-random sequence? Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tP-Ipsat90c)

Comment: I have tried over 100 times and got 2 almost always, both on emulator and phone.

Comment: What I men is that you can't possibly assess randomness by looking at the sequence, we're only humans :) "_I have tried over 100 times and got 2 almost always_" - how many times did you get `2` over 100 tries?

Comment: I understand what you mean, and you are correct to assume I'm doing something wrong or that it's a matter of perspective. But I'm working on this project for over a year and almost every time I get a 2. In the beginning I assumed it was just bad luck, but over time I kept seeing this pattern. I even tried before writing this comment, and got a 2 five times before getting a 1. I checked all of my code (and I'm a professional Java dev), researched the web but can't find a reason why this is happening.

Comment: I wasn't assuming you were doing something wrong, it just sounds like a really weird issue, I think that you could log some data to make the problem more clear. If the distribution of 0, 1 and 2 doesn't tend to 1/3 each than maybe knowing what is the actual distribution could help find the cause of the problem.

Comment: I did log it, but was to lazy to count :)

Comment: Trying to "eyeball" random data to determine if it is random enough is not very useful. You have to compute some statistics on the outputs.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
In that case you can try to use getInstanceStrong() method as specified [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/SecureRandom.html#getInstanceStrong()]) and see if that produces the results you want. Since JDK8 the `getInstanceStrong()` method will return the strongest SecureRandom implementation available on the platform.

Comment: I want values in the interval [0, 2]. The problem is that I mostly get '2' and very very rarely '0' or '1'.

Comment: I tried the implementation with the strong instance and the results were `0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,2,1,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,1,2` I hope this would work for you as well.

Comment: @AlexParvan, unless you are dealing with (quoting the doc) "high-value/long-lived secrets like RSA public/private keys", using `getInstanceStrong()` is overkill and might cause severe problems if not enough random data is available and entropy has to be gathered causing a call to the SecureRandom to block.